# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'CloudFunction<Change<DocumentSnapshot>>'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Error: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'CloudFunction>' received on my firebase cloud function, anyone knows how to fix it?

```js
exports.rebuildFormTriggerClientDetails = functions.firestore.
document('clientDetails/{details}').onUpdate((change)  => {
  const afterDoc = change.after.data();
  const documentId = change.after.id

  if (afterDoc)

  {
    let docUsers = db.collection("clientDetails").doc(documentId);
    //var userMap: {[key: string]: any} = {};
    let caseArray: Array<string>;
    caseArray = afterDoc.CaseRefArray;

    for (var valCase of caseArray) {
      console.log(valCase); 
      console.log(documentId);

        createObjectDocument(docUsers,valCase);
    }
  }

}).then(() => {
  console.log("Successfully updated document!");
}).catch((error: any) => {
  console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
});
```

The createObjectDocument function here. Could this function be the cause of the error?

```js
function createObjectDocument(document: any, caseNumber: String)

{
  document.get().then(function(doc: any) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(doc.data())) {
          console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
         if (key != "CaseRefArray")
         {
          db.collection("casesToExport").doc(caseNumber).update({key : value });
         }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error: any) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});

}
```

Comment: Could you provide your `createObjectDocument()` method.

Comment: I added the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
exports.rebuildFormTriggerClientDetails = functions.firestore.
document('clientDetails/{details}').onUpdate((change)  => {
  //const before = change.before;  // DataSnapshot before the change
  const afterDoc = change.after.data();
  const documentId = change.after.id

  if (afterDoc)

  {
    let docUsers = db.collection("clientDetails").doc(documentId);
    //var userMap: {[key: string]: any} = {};
    let caseArray: Array<string>;
    caseArray = afterDoc.CaseRefArray;

    for (var valCase of caseArray) {
      console.log(valCase); 
      console.log(documentId);

        createObjectDocument(docUsers,valCase);
    }
  }

});



function createObjectDocument(document: any, caseNumber: String)

{
  document.get().then(function(doc: any) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(doc.data())) {
          console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
         if (key != "CaseRefArray")
         {
          db.collection("casesToExport").doc(caseNumber).update({key : value })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Successfully updated document!");
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
            });
         }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error: any) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});

}
```

Your `.then()` call have to be when you update your document in your db and that's done in your `createObjectDocument()` function

Comment: db.collection("casesToExport").doc(caseNumber).update({key : value }) is never called for some reason

Comment: maybe because of the key value that you have there? what does your console log of `console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);` returns?

Comment: all the fields in the same format as this one  Client_Mobile_Tel: 07783602211

Comment: So you are sure that your if statement is true right or did you test that with a `console.log()`?

Comment: I managed to call that function but it only created a new field key : value . It seems it does not recognise the key value

Comment: But in your console.log() you get the desired output right?

Comment: yes, it prints the correct values. The if statement is correct as well